# Php/mysql insert information if Id's match Else insert different information

Tags: php, mysql

Okay so this has been modified there is still 3 tables board, account, log

Thanks to Bryan Moyles he kind of give me an epiphany

here's my code

```
$query=$S->query("
    SELECT
        `TBL`.`LAcc`,
        `TBL`.`AId`,
        `TBL`.`Add`,
        `TBL`.`Lost`,
        `TBL`.`LDate`,
        `TBL`.`FDate`

        FROM (
            SELECT 
                (SELECT SUM(`Add`) FROM `m_rules` GROUP BY `Group`) AS `Add`,
                `S`.`Account` as `LAcc`,
                `P`.`Id` as `AId`,
                SUM(`S`.`Loss`*`S`.`Multiple`) AS `Lost`,
                MAX(`S`.`Timestamp`) AS `LDate`,
                MIN(`S`.`Timestamp`) AS `FDate`
                    FROM `log` AS S,`account` AS P

            GROUP BY `P`.`Id`
        ) as `TBL`
        WHERE `TBL`.`FDate` <= NOW()
        AND `TBL`.`LDate` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)

") or die(mysql_error());

    while($Log=$S->fetch($query)) { 

        if($Log['AId']==$Log['LAcc']) {
            $Score=$Log['Add']-$Log['Lost'];
        } else {
            $Score='Bonus';
        }

        /*
            echoing to see results
        */
        echo $Log['AId'].' : '.$Score.'<br />';

        /* 
        This is what the query would look like Thanks to Bryan Moyles,

        $S->query("INSERT INTO `board` (`Account`,`Score`, `Date`)VALUES('".$Log['Id']."', '".$Score."', 'NOW()') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Score = '".$Score."'");
        */
    }
```

Here you go all results: Group by Account ID

```
Account Id:4, Log Account:5, Add: 97.64236, Lost:141.11371 LastDate:2012-05-04 22:07:46, FirstDate:2012-05-04 22:05:48, Score:Bonus
Account Id:5, Log Account:5, Add: 97.64236, Lost:141.11371 LastDate:2012-05-04 22:07:46, FirstDate:2012-05-04 22:05:48, Score:-43.47135
Account Id:6, Log Account:5, Add: 97.64236, Lost:141.11371 LastDate:2012-05-04 22:07:46, FirstDate:2012-05-04 22:05:48, Score:Bonus
Account Id:7, Log Account:5, Add: 97.64236, Lost:141.11371 LastDate:2012-05-04 22:07:46, FirstDate:2012-05-04 22:05:48, Score:Bonus
Account Id:8, Log Account:5, Add: 97.64236, Lost:141.11371 LastDate:2012-05-04 22:07:46, FirstDate:2012-05-04 22:05:48, Score:Bonus
```

GROUP BY Log Account ID

```
Account Id:4, Log Account:4, Add: 97.64236, Lost:119.67095 LastDate:2012-05-04 22:07:46, FirstDate:2012-05-04 22:06:29, Score:-22.02859
Account Id:4, Log Account:5, Add: 97.64236, Lost:542.30295 LastDate:2012-05-04 22:06:54, FirstDate:2012-05-04 22:05:48, Score:Bonus
Account Id:4, Log Account:6, Add: 97.64236, Lost:43.59465 LastDate:2012-05-04 22:07:06, FirstDate:2012-05-04 22:07:06, Score:Bonus
```

I see the problem just not sure of the solution..

**SOLVED!**

I replaced

```
FROM `log` AS S,`account` AS P
```

With

```
FROM `account` AS `P` LEFT JOIN `log` AS `S` ON `P`.`Id`=`S`.`Account`
```

in the original query (before I modified and changed it on here) I had the account and log in reverse along with the `P`.`Id`=`S`.`Account` which didn't work so I just swapped log and account around and it works.. can't believe that was the issue but thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you would ever come across a situation where the log didn't exist, being that you're building your data off of the results of a query. However, you're inserting the primary key, and you can catch the duplicate key error, and run an update accordingly.

Check out this article
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

```
$S->query("INSERT INTO `board` (`Account`,`Score`, `Date`)VALUES('".$Log['Id']."', '".$Score."', 'NOW()') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Score = '".$Score."'");
```

Comment: to be honest I don't know why I added that myself yesterday my head wasn't on right but thank you for the help.

Comment: Okay so I done a bit of reading and understand what this string is doing which it will be very useful instead of having two queries for inserting and updating, Although I can use this in the query its not what am looking to do. basically in the table log there is a field called account which is the ID of the table account and if they match then I want it to submit the score but if log account does not match the ID from the account table then I would like to add different information like bonus points as an example. sorry if it wasn't clear enough in my post.

Comment: okay so I modified my post based on what I have at the moment its providing some results but not doing what its meant to do. hopefully you have the answer to my problems yet again thank you

Comment: For a little bit of added clarity, can you also add the entire output of the sql query to your original question? I have a few theories, but seeing the actual data returned would help greatly

Comment: Just have to say thank you for the help if it wasn't for you suggesting to display all the information I probably wouldn't of figured this out on top of that I learned a simpler way to insert/update using duplicate ID so thank you again